# Would any CPython 2.7 code work in Jython 2.7b3?

Tags: python, migration, lxml, jython

Frank Wierzbicki in his [blog post](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.gr/2014/08/jython-27-beta3-released.html) has written "Jython 2.7b3 brings us up to language level compatibility with the 2.7 version of CPython."

Does it mean that any CPython 2.7 code would work with Jython?

I have a large code written in CPython 2.7. Since we want to integrate it with JAVA modules, I would be extremely interested in a way of migrating to Jython without rewriting of code. Considering libraries, I use a lot of lxml which (as described [here](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Jython)) was not compatible with the previous versions Jython.

Comment: Anything written in pure python should work in Jython. But anything third-party packages with C code will almost certainly not. If `lxml` has C code, which it seems that it does, then it will probably still not work.

Answer (score 3):

No, not *all* code that works in CPython 2.7 will work in Jython, in the same way that some code is tied to a specific OS and won't work on other OS-es (e.g. Windows-specific Python code won't work on Linux, and vice versa).

The *syntax* will work, but if the script requires specific add-on modules such as `lxml`, then those will **not** work. That is because `lxml` is a C-API extension, and Jython doesn't support the Python C-API.

Similarly, if your code uses the `multiprocessing` module, then it also won't work on Jython, because that part of the standard library is not included.